# Git aborting due to possible respository corruption

Tags: networking, configuration, git, ralink

I am trying to execute:

```
git clone https://gitorious.org/wive-rtnl-ralink-rt305x-routers-firmware/wive-rtnl-ralink-rt305x-routers-firmware.git
```

But, it is giving me the following error:

```
Cloning into 'wive-rtnl-ralink-rt305x-routers-firmware'...
remote: Counting objects: 202544, done.
remote: warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

I have tried to solve the problem ([git clone is aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side even though memory settings are done properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810795/git-clone-is-aborting-due-to-possible-repository-corruption-on-the-remote-side-e)) by the following:

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.SizeLimit "100m" 
git config --global pack.threads "1"
git config --global pack.window "0"
```

Still the problem is not solved. Any reply would be of immense help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That points to a problem in the **remote** repository (on gitorious), ask the author(s).